# Trouble downloading Excel files all of a sudden

Tags: php, excel, apache2, mime-types

I'm all of a sudden having a hard time downloading excel spreadsheets from our webserver.
We use apache2.2.22 and php 5.4.45-0+deb7u7.
The files are corrupt after download. 
I've verified the spreadsheet files are OK. (I'm able to open them w/o problem if I don't download them via the browser then try to look at them.)
Here's the response header:

`Cache-Control       no-store, no-cache, must-reval…te, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection      Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length      22
Content-Type        text/html
Date            Mon, 29 Jan 2018 17:56:52 GMT
Expires         Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive      timeout=3, max=100
Pragma          no-cache
Server          Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary            Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By        PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u7`

I'm just totally stumped here.
I've also been trying to add a mime-type like this:

`case "xlsx":
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel-xml");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
break;`

Nothing seems to be working. (but it used to work flawlessly.)
Any help or ideas come much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It could have something to do with your `Expires` line. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires). If you can modify your `Cache-Control` [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) it might fix your issue.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the idea. :-) I've tried a few combinations noted on the link you sent. No luck as of yet, but I'll keep at it.